# How can I load an extension inside a Cog in Discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a file, `ticket.py`, and I'm currently loading the command into my bot using `client.load_extension(ticket)`.

`ticket.py` looks like this:

```
@commands.command(name='ticket')
async def ticket(ctx,*, args=None):
    //do stuff

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_command(ticket)
```

and I load it in the main file:

```
client=commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
client.load_extension("ticket")
```

Which works fine, but currently, the `ticket` command is not associated with a Cog. I want to know how I can load it inside a Cog (for example, so that it is associated with the `Utilities` Cog).

Normally, I would simply define the command inside a class:

```
class Utilities(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command(name='ticket')
    async def ticket(self, ctx, *, args=None):
        //do stuff
```

However, my code is rather long and tedious and I would prefer to deal with it in a separate file (hence `ticket.py`, which is outside of `main.py`).

How can I load the `ticket` command into the `Utilities` Cog? (while keeping `ticket.py` and `main.py` separate).

Comment: Can you show us the structure of `ticket.py`? Currently, it looks like you have multiple questions in one if I got that right.

Comment: I'm only asking one question -- how can I load the `ticket` command into a Cog (" `Utilities` "), when the class `Utilities` is defined in `main.py`, and `ticket` is defined in a separate file `ticket.py`? (I updated my question to make it clearer)

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? Keep it in 2 files and make two Cogs/Classes out of it...

Comment: That's a reasonable alternative, but the program for `ticket` is rather long and I would prefer to keep it separate, So I'm wondering whether it's possible. Although if it's not, that's what I will end up doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the actual code for the command in the other file and simply call it directly from inside the cog.

Suppose this is called `command_ticket.py` and you have a bunch of random arguments:

```py
async def _ticket(ctx, number: int, whatever: str, consume_rest: str):
    # do things
```

Then, you just invoke that in the cog:

```py
import command_ticket
class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    @commands.command(name='ticket')
    async def ticket(ctx, number: int, whatever: str, *, consume_rest: str = None):
        command_ticket._ticket(ctx, number, whatever, consume_rest)
```

Note that in this case there would be no need to add a separate extension for the internal ticket function - you can simply register the extension with the cog.

Comment: That's a very clever solution. Thank you so much for your help!